# select records from one table based on table B records

Tags: sql, recursion, nested

I have 2 tables representing Parent-Child relationship.

Parent Id has a status of T.

[image]

```
select Child_id from table B where parent_id ='2';
```

Total number of child records are 7 under this parent id.

and among these 7 records, one of them is parent to 3 child records.

I need some help writing a query which should return me all the child records for a given parent_id
so total number of child records in this case would be (7-1) + 3 = 9;

```
here is what I have tried already.
--this gives me the 7 child records
select distinct Child_id from table B 
where parent_id in(
select parent_id from Table A where status = 'T' 
and A.parent_id = B.parent_id
and A.parent_id ='2');
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` query to merge two levels (assuming there are only 2 levels), e.g.:

```
SELECT b.child_id
FROM tableB b JOIN tableA a ON b.parent_id = a.parent_id
WHERE a.status = 'T'

UNION

SELECT b.child_id
FROM tableB b JOIN tableB b1 ON b.parent_id = b1.child_id
JOIN tableA a ON b1.parent_id = a.parent_id
WHERE a.status = 'T'
```